# How to pass variable to function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with my code and I am trying everything :(

Here is the code and thank you to everyone helping! :)

```
import turtle

def main():
    print("Project 1 by Amanda Basant")

main()

def draw_filled_square(turtle,size,color):
    turtle.fillcolor(color) 
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for i in range(4):
           turtle.forward(size)
           turtle.left(90)
    
turtle.end_fill()

def draw_picture():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    amanda = turtle.Turtle()
    amanda.up()
    amanda.goto(0,0)
    amanda.down()

    draw_filled_square(amanda,300,"blue")
    draw_filled_square(amanda,300,"green")

draw_picture()
```

I want to draw [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPaeC.png) this ultimately. I fixed the initial problem I had. I can do the letters on the box, but I am struggling bad on how to fill the boxes and run with the turtle now. Does anyone know why the boxes won't fill?

Comment: what error are u getting now?

Comment: Your indentation does not look right, I assume the `for` loop should be nested within your  `draw_filled_square` function?

Comment: I am getting an error saying size is not defined, let me try that

Comment: I nested the for loop, now I am getting an error saying "blue is not defined"

Comment: simply `blue` will become variable, use quote, `"blue"` means string. same for green.

Comment: `blue` and `green` should be strings. `"blue"` and `"green"`. Also, `turtle.begin_fill()` shouldn't have any arguments. try using `turtle.fillcolor(color)` before it.

Comment: I did, it runs now, but the turtle is messed up and not filling the color

Comment: please check edit if u can !!

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code in your question. Is `turtle.end_fill()` indented inside the `draw_filled_square()` function?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the boxes aren't filled is that `turtle.end_fill()` is *after* the `raw_filled_square()` function instead of being the *last line* of the function.  The reason you're not getting two boxes is that you're drawing one atop the other.  Let's rework this code a little bit to make it draw the boxes from your desired image:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def main():
    print("Project 1 by Amanda Basant")

    screen = Screen()

    draw_picture()

    screen.exitonclick()

def draw_filled_square(turtle, size, color):
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

def draw_picture():
    amanda = Turtle()

    for _ in range(2):
        draw_filled_square(amanda, 300, "green")
        amanda.right(90)
        draw_filled_square(amanda, 300, "blue")
        amanda.right(90)

main()
```

[image]